# How would I use the method of differences here to find the sum of this finite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I need to use the method of differences to show that $$\sum_ {r=2} ^n \frac {1} {r(r-1)(r+1)} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}$$

I've already found $\frac{1}{r(r-1)(r+1)}$ as partial fractions $\Bigl( \frac{-1}{r}+\frac{1}{2(r-1)}+\frac{1}{2(r+1)} \Bigr)$.

After that, I factorised out $\frac{1}{2}$ to get $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_ {r=1}^n\Bigl(\frac{-2}{r}+\frac{1}{r-1}+\frac{1}{r+1}\Bigr)$$

I then found the sum to be $-2+1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}$.

I then did $$\sum_{r=2}^n\frac{1}{r(r-1)(r+1)}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r(r-1)(r+1)}-\sum_{r=1}^1\frac{1}{r(r-1)(r+1)}$$$$=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}$$$$=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}$$

I think I've made a mistake somewhere and the $2n+1$ should just be $1$ to get $\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}$ but I'm not sure where. I could include more details about how I found the sum to be $\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}$ if that would help.

Comment: The summations should start at $r=2$ in accordance with the sum. (The case $r=1$ will lead to a zero in the denominator)

Answer (score 1):

Observe we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r(r-1)(r+1)}=\frac{1}{2r(r-1)}-\frac{1}{2r(r+1)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The intermediate terms vanish within  a series of $3$ consecutive partial decompositions:
\begin{align}
\frac1{(r-1)(r-2)r}&=\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{r-1}}+\frac{1}{2(r-2)}\color{red}{+\frac{1}{2r} }\\
\frac1{r(r-1)(r+1)}&=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{r}}\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{2(r-1)}}\color{green}{+\frac{1}{2(r+1)}}\\
\frac1{(r+1)r(r+2)}&=\color{green}{-\frac{1}{r+1}}\color{red}{+\frac{1}{2r}}+\frac{1}{2(r+2)}
\end{align}